# JSR223 and its Cryptic exceptions

Tags: groovy, jsr, jsr223

Is there a way to get better error messages from JSR 223? I'm trying to use it to run Groovy scripts and whenever there is a problem in the execution, I get exceptions that are truly crypic. Here is an example:

```
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.   invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:270)
      at    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
     at Script1.search(Script1.groovy:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:227)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:77)
    at Script1.processEvent(Script1.groovy:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
```

Comment: pasting the search method of your script (especially line 28) would help :-)  You might also be able to catch this sort of thing and use the StackTraceUtils class to clean it? http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StackTraceUtils.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there are only two things I can think of.

1. Use Intellij IDEA, it collaposes the stack traces so that you only initialy see the bits that relate to your code. I think the community edition has groovy support in it now so you might get away with the free version.
2. Get good at scanning these stack traces for your code. In  your example Script1.groovy line 28 is attempting to fit a square peg in a round hole.

You might be able to configure your IDE/log reader to highlight the *.groovy lines or something like that

Sorry can't be much more helpful.

PS. don't worry it isn't you, these stacktraces are designed to mess with your mind